# How do i obtain foreign table field using string value for fieldname with reflection and entity framework

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, entity-framework, reflection

I have 2 tables.  An asset table that links using a foreign key to a device table.

To get the device_name field of the asset, in linq i would use:

```
dim device as string = result.device.device_name
```

The Result object contains the unique record from an earlier linq to entity framework command.

Now I have a need to allow end users to specify their fields they want in a report.  I will end up having a string name of the field, so tried using reflection

```
dim name as string = result.GetType().GetProperty("asset_name").GetValue(result)
```

This returns the asset_name field so i thought great, i should be able to get the relating foreign table field value.

```
dim device = result.GetType().GetProperty("device").GetValue(result).GetType.GetProperty("device_name").GetValue(result.device)
```

This works however i had to specify the object.  As i will have other tables linking to the first table, would i have to write additional code to check what object and manually specify?  Or am i going into this wrongly?  Any help and advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a cleaner solution, so this is how i did it:

```
dim field as string ="device.device_name" 
dim output as string =""
dim subtable as string ="" 

If field.Contains(".") Then 
    subtable = field.Substring(0, field.IndexOf(".")) 
    field = field.Substring(field.IndexOf(".") + 1)
End If
If subtable <> "" Then
  Select case subtable
    Case "device" 
        If Not IsNothing(result.device.GetType().GetProperty(field)) Then
            output = result.device.GetType().GetProperty(field).GetValue(result.device)
        End If
  End Select
Else
    If Not IsNothing(result.GetType().GetProperty(field)) Then 
        output= result.GetType().GetProperty(field).GetValue(reult)
    End If
End If
Return output
```